# How to get name of a shared variable in Theano?

Tags: python, theano

How to get name of a shared variable in Theano? I see that printing it or using `str()` works, but is the correct way to do so? Is there any function similar to `X.get_value()` (e.g. `X.get_name()`)?

Example:

```
import theano as th
import numpy as np

X = th.shared(name='xx', value=np.zeros(shape=(2), dtype=th.config.floatX), borrow=True)

print(X)              # print 'xx'
print(str(X) == 'xx') # print 'True'
print(X.get_value())  # print [ 0.  0.]
```

Comment: X.name? just like that?

Comment: @JamesTobin Thanks, it works, good guess  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the name of a shared variable `x` by getting `x.name`. Unfortunately this is [not documented](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/compile/shared.html).